# creacion de login en php y msql

Tags: php, mysql, css, html5, crud

Estoy intentado hacer un login con php y msql y al momento de ingresar un usuario no registrado me muestra esto

> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Tienda\admin_control\login\validar.php on line 18
>
> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> C:\xa[![introducir la descripción de la imagen
> aquí][1]][1]mpp\htdocs\Tienda\admin_control\login\validar.php on line
> 22

```php
<?php

$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$clave=$_POST['clave'];

session_start();

$_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;

include('db.php');

$consulta="SELECT*FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario' and clave='$clave'";

$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

$filas=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

if($filas['id_cargo'] == 1) { //ADMINSTRADOR

header("location:../../admin/productos.php");

}else if($filas['id_cargo'] == 2){ // CLIENTE
header("location:../../index.php");
}
else{
?>

<?php
include("index.php");
?>

<h1 class="bad">No existe ningun usuario con esas creedenciales <a href="#">¿Deseas crear una cuenta?</a> </h1>

<?php
}

mysqli_free_result($resultado);

mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Comment: Podrías poner tu código en texto, es difícil saber cual es la linea, pues no tiene indice.

Comment: Segun parece la consulta no devuelve nada y de ahí el resto de errores. Haz la consulta manualmente a ver que te devuelve y analiza mejor donde tienes el fallo (quizás un usuario o una password equivocadas, o una consulta errónea). De todos modos, te recomiendo el uso de [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) y [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Comment: Cuando no existe el usuario, mysqli [devuelve](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-array-returnvalues) `null` y se le asigna a `$filas`. Entonces al intentar sacar el valor de `$filas['id_cargo']` aparecerá el error que describes. Una solución sencilla es que cambies el orden las condiciones `if/else`, la primera opción debe ser: `if(!$filas) { /* El usuario no existe */}` y luego las demás.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es porque **$filas=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);** puede que no tenga nada debido a que no validas si hay o no resultados provenientes de la base de datos.

Deberías de hacer esto antes:

```php
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($resultado)
if($num == 0){
    echo '<h1 class="bad">No existe ningun usuario con esas creedenciales <a href="#">¿Deseas crear una cuenta?</a> </h1>';
    exit();
}
```

Con esto validas si la consulta a la base de datos tiene o no resultados, es decir si el login es correcto o no, te recomiendo también cambiar un poco a consultas preparadas de mysqli para evitar inyecciones a la base de datos, luego quizás migrar a algún framework como Laravel, sin embargo con eso que te acabo de pasar de ejemplo bastará.